# Change Position of UIAlertView

Tags: iphone

Any one help to change the position of UIAlertView

Answer (score 9):

As for any UIView subclass you can apply affine transform to UIAlertView, e.g. to move it you can use:

```
UIAlert *alert = //create alert
alert.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( x, y);
[alert show];
[alert release];
```